# How to create an array of dates spaced 2 weeks apart in VBA?

Tags: vba, date

I have seen examples on how to create an array of all the dates, or a date every month between a start date and end date here. However, I am trying to create an array of dates every 2 weeks specifically between a start and end date.

Ex. if `startdate = 7/18/2021` and `enddate = 12/28/2025`, I want an array that is:
`array = {7/18/2021, 8/1/2021, 8/15/2021, ..., 12/28/2025}`

How exactly can I do this? I tried using a recorded macro but it only uses the xlFillDefault and doesn't actually specify the algorithm used.

```
Sub get2weekdates()
'
' get2weekdates Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "7/18/2021"
    Range("D6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "8/1/2021"
    Range("D5:D6").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D5:D121"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("D5:D121").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to check into the SEQUENCE function in Excel; you may not need VBA? =SEQUENCE((EndDate - StartDate)/14 + 1, 1, StartDate, 14)

Comment: basically you can loop with a for loop and add 14 to a double that starts at the double value of the start date.  In Excel dates are just double, the number of days from 12/31/1899.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the `Function ArrayWithDates()` is to take 2 parameters - the first day and the size as an optional one *(in the example, 14 is 2 weeks, you may write 21 for 3 weeks or 20 for 2 weeks and 6 days)*.

Once it gets these, it enlarges the array based on the size with this line - `ReDim result(size - 1)`. As the 0th element of the array is known, it is assigned outside the loop - `result(0) = firstDay`.

Then, in the loop, the other elements are assigned, and each one is the next day, using `DateAdd()`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = ArrayWithDates(#7/18/2021#)
    
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        Debug.Print i; myArray(i)
    Next i
    
End Sub

Public Function ArrayWithDates(firstDay As Date, Optional size As Long = 14) As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    If size < 1 Then
        ArrayWithDates = Array()
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ReDim result(size)
    result(0) = firstDay
    
    For i = 1 + LBound(result) To UBound(result)
        result(i) = DateAdd("D", 1, result(i - 1))
    Next i
    
    ArrayWithDates = result
    
End Function
```

The result looks as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dates are just doubles that look like a date.  we just need to loop and add 14 to the start till we hit the end date:

```
Sub get2weekdates()

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim strtdt As Double
        strtdt = .Range("C1").Value2
        
        Dim eddt As Double
        eddt = .Range("c2").Value2
        
        Dim nmDts As Long
        nmDts = (eddt - strtdt) / 14 + 1
        
        Dim otArray As Variant
        ReDim otArray(1 To nmDts, 1 To 1)
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To nmDts
            otArray(i, 1) = strtdt + ((i - 1) * 14)
        Next i
        
        .Range("D5").Resize(nmDts, 1).Value = otArray
        .Range("D5").Resize(nmDts, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

---

But as stated by @pdtcaskey with Office 365 this can be a simple formula:

```
=SEQUENCE((C2 - C1)/14 + 1,, C1, 14)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the advice! In the statement ```=SEQUENCE((C2 - C1)/14 + 1,, C1, 14)``` are the two commas after the first element necessary?

Comment: @Jonathan yes it will use the default `1` in the number of columns.  You could do: `=SEQUENCE((C2 - C1)/14 + 1, 1, C1, 14)` but that is two more keystrokes for the same output